# c# console application unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, console-application

```
        int ValueOne, ValueTwo, Numchar, Total;
    Console.WriteLine("This Is A Program For doing any Of the four mathematical Proccesses");
    Console.WriteLine("You can Add , substract , Divide And Multiply");
    Console.WriteLine("When Asked Please Type The Values Or The Proccesses You Want.");
    Console.WriteLine("Please Type The First Value");
    ValueOne = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
    Console.WriteLine("Please Type The Second Value");
    ValueTwo = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Number Of The Proccess/Character You Want Meaning That (1 = +) , (2 = -) , (3 = *) , (4 = /)");
    Numchar = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
    if (Numchar == 1)
        Total = ValueOne + ValueTwo;
    if (Numchar == 2)
        Total = ValueOne + ValueTwo;
    if (Numchar == 3)
        Total = ValueOne * ValueTwo;
    if (Numchar == 4)
        Total = ValueOne / ValueTwo;
    Console.WriteLine("The Total Is :");
    Console.WriteLine(Total);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

the Console.WriteLine(Total); 
at the end is apparently an unassigned local variable , though it should be assigned from the Lines beneath the "If" lines, also note that I'm new in visual studio and i just started taking The Courses , also , i don't think this is a duplicate because the other post's fix Didn't Work for me.

Comment: If Numchar is 5 what is the value of Total? This is a problem for the compiler and there are duplicates for this question ad nauseam.

Comment: If numchar == 5 or higher it will never be assigned to. So it is throwing an error

Comment: What did you try that “Didn't Work”?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your code didn't produce an error, and compiled and ran. What do you think would happen if `NumChar` wasn't `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`?

Your code would never reach any of the statements in your `if`s there, and would never assign an initial value to `Total`. Since this is entirely possible given your program (and would be impossible to check for in general -- see the Halting Problem), the error is substantiated and necessary.